# Modular document compiling without some child documents

Tags: pdftex, input

I am creating a modular TeX document with many child documents, using the `\input` command. After inputting the first 10 child documents, everything compiles as it should. However, after I add another section to the parent document, it says that it compiles correctly, but the new sections do not appear in the output. Here is a sample of the code:

```
\documentclass{Lesson_Plans}  
\begin{document}

\input{Math101/Chapter1/1-1}  
\input{Math101/Chapter1/1-2}  
...  
\input{Math101/Chapter2/2-4}

\end{document}
```

So, all sections up to 2-3 compile perfectly, but nothing from 2-4 onward appears in the output.

I have already checked to make sure that all of the child documents compile correctly on their own. Interestingly, if I comment out all of the earlier sections, then sections 2-4 onward do appear in the output. However, if I only comment out some of them, then they do not appear. Also, if I put section 2-4 before 2-3 in the code, then it is still section 2-3 that appears in the output.

Any help or thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: I would guess that one of your input documents has `\end{document}` in it (or `\stop`)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was caused by the OP having a stray `\end{document}` in one of the included files.